# How to convert interpreted linq query to local linq query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

Below is `LINQ` to `SQL` query?

```
Regex wordCounter = new Regex (@"\b(\w|[-'])+\b");
IEnumerable<MedicalArticle> sqlQuery = dataContext.MedicalArticles
.Where (article => article.Topic == "influenza");
IEnumerable<MedicalArticle> localQuery = sqlQuery
.Where (article => wordCounter.Matches (article.Abstract).Count < 100);
```

Exception occurs because SQL Server does not support regular expression. How can I cast the `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use ToList() or AsEnumerable() like sqlQuery.ToList().Where(...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the query on SQL server, get the results as a list, then run the RegEx.   I have done this by adding a ".ToList()".

```
var sqlResults = dataContext.MedicalArticles
.Where (article => article.Topic == "influenza").ToList();

Regex wordCounter = new Regex (@"\b(\w|[-'])+\b");
IEnumerable<MedicalArticle> localQuery = sqlResults 
.Where (article => wordCounter.Matches (article.Abstract).Count < 100);
```

If this was production code, I would *consider* hand written SQL using the "LIKE" operator, rather then using a Regex on the client side.